# How to replace UTF-8 to similar Latin letters in a String?

Tags: java, ldap

I am having a String

```
s = M\\c3\\a4nager
```

I want to replace `\\c3\\a4` with its equivalent Latin character `ä`
So the String should be

```
s = Mänager
```

I searched a lot how to do it in java please help me with the same
I want to handle all such UTF-8 characters in my code.

Comment: Its normal input to a method

Comment: These are not Java unicode code point representations.

Comment: its  aUTF-8 hex representaion , these are used as a part of filter in LDAP

Comment: Is [this](https://numberformat.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/convert-utf-8-unicode-to-ascii-latin-1/) what you are looking for?

Comment: for UTF8 represenation of these letters you can refer this http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x

Comment: @Mike : no in that it is done for unicode characters, i am luking for UTF8 hex,.. I got one code which converts it reverse from latin character to UTF-8 , but i need it reverse , that code is : http://blog.dzhuvinov.com/?p=585

Comment: Can't you write the code yourself?  'Cos this question is starting to sound like a request for a library recommendation ... which is off-topic.  (And seriously, it is probably just 20-30 lines of code to convert the string to a byte array, decoding the hex excapes, and then decode the bytes to a string using `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unescape the LDAP string you could use following snippet

```
// import javax.naming.ldap.Rdn;
String escapedValue = "M\\c3\\a4nager";
Object unescapedValue = Rdn.unescapeValue(escapedValue);
System.out.println("escapedValue   = " + escapedValue);
System.out.println("unescapedValue = " + unescapedValue);
```

output

```
escapedValue   = M\c3\a4nager
unescapedValue = Mänager
```

`unescapedValue` contains the String as UTF-8. If you need another encoding you need to handle it properly.

Simple example to show the difference in bytes for different encodings.

```
byte[] latinBytes = ((String)unescapedValue).getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
byte[] utf8Bytes = ((String)unescapedValue).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

System.out.println("latin1: " + Arrays.toString(latinBytes));
System.out.println("utf8  : " + Arrays.toString(utf8Bytes));
```

output

```
latin1: [77, -28, 110, 97, 103, 101, 114]
utf8  : [77, -61, -92, 110, 97, 103, 101, 114]
```

Comment: Hi, when i tried executing in normal java application,  escapedValue=Sekret\\c3\\a4rIn and I got the result as, ..unescapedvalue=.SekretärIn but when executed in my application its showing unescapedValue=SekretÃ¤rIn .. some RFC format not supported.. Can you please suggest

Comment: @user3363047 Which looks correct for me. Or what's the problem?

Comment: unescapedValue=SekretÃ¤rIn  .. this value is not required value .. required value is unescapedvalue=.SekretärIn ..

Comment: @user3363047 This looks more like a convertion problem from UTF-8 to Latin-1. For example when you print the string on a non-unicode aware terminal (e.g. Windows CMD shell). See my updated answer.

Comment: Object unescapedValue = Rdn.unescapeValue(escapevalue);byte[] utf8Bytes = ((String)unescapedValue).getBytes("UTF16");
newFilter = new String(utf8Bytes,"UTF16"); I tried this in my code but did not work,..  is there any way to set format in rdn constructor or something